Weird indefinite integration in Mathematica explicitly introduces a pole that does not exist
Consider the following code:
expr1[Ech_, Ep_, mch_, mp_, mV_, Lp_] = (
 mp (2 Ech^2 + 2 Ech mp + mch^2) - 
  Ep (2 Ech mp + mch^2))/((Ech^2 - mch^2) ((2 mp (Ep - mp))/Lp^2 + 
    1)^2 (2 Ep mp - 2 mp^2 + mV^2)^2)
expr2[Ech_, Ep_, mch_, mp_, mV_, Lp_] = 
 Integrate[expr1[Ech, Ep, mch, mp, mV, Lp], Ep]
Limit[expr2[Ech, Ep, mch, mp, mV, Lp], mV -> Lp]

It defines a function of some parameters and a variable Ep, and then performs indefinite integration over Ep. The initial function is perfectly finite for Lp>0 and mV>0 (in particular, for Lp = mV. However, the integration is performed in a weird way, such that a pole term 1/(Lp^2-mV^2)^3 appears. It actually does not exist (which is shown by the third line), but it is only possible to get rid off it only if performing the limit. In the case when I just insert mV->Lp, Mathematica returns singularity.
I cannot remove the pole using the commands like Simplify, FullSimplify, etc., whereas the commands like Cancel lead to a very long expression which still explicitly contains the unexisting pole. Could you please tell me how to transform the expression such that it would be explicitly pole-free?
Edit
The domain of definition of Ep is Ep>mp>0. The problem may arise from the denominator 2mp(Ep-mp)/Lp^2 + 1. However, it is a positively-defined function assuming within the domain of definition, and it surely does not involve mV. I have tried to integrate using Assumptions->Ep>mp>0 && Lp > 0 && mV>0, but it still returns this pole.

First FullSimplify and you should get this (Mathematica 14.1) (Lp^4 (2 Ech^2 mp - (Ep - mp) (mch^2 + 2 Ech mp)))/((Ech - mch) (Ech +mch) (Lp^2 + 2 (Ep - mp) mp)^2 (2 (Ep - mp) mp + mV^2)^2) then I tried to see what Ep would set that last bracket in the denominator to zero by doing Solve[2 (Ep - mp) mp + mV^2 == 0, Ep] which gave Ep -> (2 mp^2 - mV^2)/(2 mp), so then pass this into Limit like this and notice there's an infinity in there...

Limit[expr, Ep -> (2 mp^2 - mV^2)/(2 mp)]  giving (Lp^4 (4 Ech^2 mp^2 + mch^2 mV^2 + 2 Ech mp mV^2) \[Infinity])/((Ech^2 - mch^2) (Lp^2 - mV^2)^2 Sign[   mp]^3)  Bug? Maybe... but the infinity makes me less confident about your assertion there is no pole, plus your test uses mV which is not the variable of integration. You need to test values of the independent variable Ep, not constants like mV.

@flinty : but the initial expression is clearly free from the pole at mV = Lp, and the indefinite integration over Ep cannot cause the pole to appear. The only possible problem is with the denominator. However, it is a positively-defined function assuming Ep>mp>0 (this is my domain of definition), and it surely does not involve mV. I have tried to integrate using Assumptions->Ep>mp>0 && Lp > 0 && mV>0, but it still returns the problem.

Usin g Apartt on the expression gives terms with Lp^2-mV^2 in the denominator. Hence their appearance in the result.

expr /. {Lp -> 1, Ech -> 4, mch -> 4, Ep -> 2, mp -> 1, mV -> 1} is ComplexInfinity. Found using FindInstance[Numerator[expr] > 0 && Denominator[expr] == 0 && mV > 0 && Lp > 0 && Ep > mp > 0 && Ech > 0, Variables[expr], Reals] which I believe has all your constraints unless you're missing some.

@flinty : in your example, the infinity arises because of Ech = mch. It would be absent for any Ech > mch.

@JohnTaylor But how does that help? You can choose an Ech that's infinitesimally larger than mch, satisfying your constraints, but the expression will still blow up. Limit[FullSimplify[   expr /. {Lp -> 1, Ech -> 4 + \[Epsilon], mch -> 4, Ep -> 2, mp -> 1,      mV -> 1}], \[Epsilon] -> 0] is still indeterminate.

I can get an answer if I impose these assumptions (mch > 0 || Ech + mch != 0) && (Ech != mch || mch <= 0) &&   0 < mp <    Ech && (mp < Ep < mp + (2 Ech^2 mp)/(mch^2 + 2 Ech mp) ||     Ep > mp + (2 Ech^2 mp)/(mch^2 + 2 Ech mp)) && Lp > 0 && mV > 0

@flinty : my point is that the origin of the fake "pole" factor has nothing to do with Ech -> mch.
